# How can I pass variables to external javascript file that can be accessed by all the functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, external-js

I have a Kendo grid whose Events property is hooked to a function(Grid_OnRowSelect) in external javascript file. There are other functions in the external javascript file ( like on button click *** $("#btnS").on('click', function () {....*** ) and few others. The Grid_OnRowSelect function and the other functions use common set of variables. How can I pass variables to an external javascript file from a view (cshtml) that can be accessed by all the functions.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
.Name("rGrid")
.Events(events => events.Change("Grid_OnRowSelect"))
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Command(command =>

 .......
 .......
 .......
```

The external js file is

```
var MYFunc = MYFunc || (function () {
var _args = {}; // private

return {
    init: function (Args) {
        _args = Args;
        // some other initialising
    },
    helloWorld: function () {
        alert('Hello World! -' + _args[0]);
    },
    Grid_OnRowSelect: function (e) {

        var data = this.dataItem(this.select());
        detailRequestID = data.ID;

        var url = _args[1] + "/" + detailRequestID;
        window.location.href = url;
    },
    onError: function (e, status) {
        //alert("A server error has occurred!");
        var url = _args[2];
        window.location.href = url;

    }
};
```

}());

How I'm trying to pass arguments

```
  <script>
    window.onload = function(){
    var searchUrl = @Url.Action("Search");
    var updateUrl = @Url.Action("Update");
    var errorUrl = @Url.Action("ServerError", "Error");
};
MYFunc.init([searchUrl, updateUrl, errorUrl]);</script><script src="~/Scripts/Index.js"></script>
```

But when Grid_OnRowSelect or any of the functions gets executed _args is undefined. What is not correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just declare a variable outside of a function in javascript it will be available to all code JS code that is loaded AFTER it. The fact that the file is external does not matter, just that it loads into the DOM after the place where you set your global variables.

Example

```
var globalVar = "I am global";
function test(){
    var copy = globalVar;//copy now == "I am global"
    var nonglobalVar = "I am not";//this is local to the function
}
var global2 = globalVar;//global2 now == "I am global"
var anotherVar = nonglobalVar;//this line will throw an error because variable is out of scope.
```

Another common tactic is to write your values to a hidden field in the html and then access that from your external functions.